# Table cells bad rendering with Google Chrome/Webkit

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, html-table

On the following code, COL1A and COL3A are not 50% height with Chrome or Webkit. It works fine with IE7 and Firefox.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td height="100%">COL 1A</td>
    <td rowspan="2">COL 2</td>
    <td>COL 3A</td>
    <td rowspan="2">
      COL 4<br/>
      COL 4<br/>
      COL 4<br/>
      COL 4<br/>
      COL 4<br/>
      COL 4<br/>
      COL 4<br/>
      COL 4<br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="100%">COL 1B</td>
    <td>COL 3B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Demo**:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/255810/Jalios/Demo/TableChrome/table2.html

I've tried to set various height (on TR or TD). I also tried to set an image with a padding or margin ... but nothing works.

Is it a Chrome bug ? Is there a turn-aroud or tips ?

Comment: In response to the answer below you suggest you'll fix these with Javascript. Would you share how you did that in an answer? Please? Other people such as myself are finding this question while trying to solve similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be a problem within webkit. I have same problems with Chrome and Safari.
This appears when having rows of specific height except some in the center. Just the last will be upscaled if there is another column with higher rowspan.
in horizontal this problem does not appear.

You have to use another table within a single cell in cols 1 and 3
and avoid rowspan

```
<table border="1">
<tr><td><table height=100%><tr><td height="100%">COL 1A</td></tr>
                <tr><td height="100%">COL 1B</td></tr>
        </table></td>
<td><td>COL 2</td>
<td>COL 3A</td>
<td>
  COL 4<br/>
  COL 4<br/>
  COL 4<br/>
...
```

Additionally you have to manage the borders for the inner table using css

Answer (score 0):

For a `td`, the `height` attribute is not part of the *strict* definition, only in *transitional*, maybe WebKit does not implement it. Try using CSS.

Edit: No luck with CSS, either. Maybe you'll have to use one row per line, then you can use correct `rowspan` attributes to generate cells with 50% height.

Comment: Thanks, COL4 is only for demo purpose, in fact I have a complexe information in COL4 that I can't split

Comment: Then you'll probably have to abandon the `table` approach and build the thing with (floating) `div`s.

Comment: Well I can't, I have to use Table (usually I don't I use DIV) but in this case I have to use Table to render my dynamic FlowChart that already works very well. I will use few lines of JavaScript to fix Webkit :(

Comment: Can you share the JS solution you used?