# HTML table - space between rows

Tags: html, html-table

I am seeing a different behavior between Firefox and Chrome for the same HTML table.

Firefox: the space between rows are equally divided.

Chrome: the space between rows are NOT equally divided.

Could someone tell me what is going on?

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/JT5ay/3/)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">AAA</td>
                <td>BBB</td>
                <td rowspan="3"CCC<br/>CCC<br/>CCC<br/>CCC<br/>CCC<br/>CCC<br/>CCC<br/>CCC<br/>CCC<br/>CCC<br/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BBB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BBB</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you look at the syntax highlighting in your linked fiddle, you'll see that something is wrong with your HTML structure. This may, or may not, have anything to do with the problem, but it's easier, and more reliable, to debug *correct* HTML.

Comment: If you change the `<br>` tags to `<br/>` it fixes the error in the fiddle, but doesn't equalize spacing in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known rendering issue with Chrome/Webkit browsers.

A user provided a solution here: [Table cells bad rendering with Google Chrome/Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706777/table-cells-bad-rendering-with-google-chrome-webkit)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use close the tag by using `<br/>` instead of `<br>`.

In compliant XHTML, all tags need to be properly closed. In this case, instead of closing the tag with `</br>`, you use the trailing `/` to do it.

```
<br></br>
```

is equivalent to

```
<br/>
```

You would do the same thing with an image element:

```
<img src="..."/>
```

Comment: it fixes the error in the fiddle, but doesn't equalize spacing in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue where I get 1px space between rows in Chrome but not in other browsers. It was solved when I added the following in the the CSS.

```
td{
   padding: 0px 0px;
   position:relative;
}
```

The key point is setting td to "position:relative". For some reason it solved the issue. Maybe the same could help in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

What if you close the third `<td...`

```
<td rowspan="3"CCC
<td rowspan="3">CCC
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I cant comment. I need 50 reputation ;)

Comment: Sorry, but those are the rules. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead#answer-214174).