# How to make Chrome browser apportion vertical space equally across all table rows?

Tags: google-chrome, html-table

I have a legacy application that uses a table to layout various items in columns and rows.  I'm finding that excess vertical space is not being apportioned equally to all of the rows in Chrome 105.0.5195.52, while it is in Firefox 102.11.0esr.  My users are having the same experience with more current versions of Chrome and also Safari.

The table is unusual in that some of the table's td elements have rowspan attributes, which seems to be the cause of the problem.  When the table's overall height is expanded to fit one column the excess height is being allocated entirely to the rows that have cells that span multiple rows.  This results in some rows of the table having disproportionate heights.

I have a simple table:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            td { border: 1px solid black; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Number</th>
                    <th style="width: 45%">One</th>
                    <th style="width: 45%">Two</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td rowspan="10">
                        <p>abc</p>
                        <p>abc</p>
                        <p>abc</p>
                        <p>abc</p>
                        <p>abc</p>
                        <p>abc</p>
                        <p>abc</p>
                        <p>abc</p>
                        <p>abc</p>
                        <p>abc</p>
                        <p>abc</p>
                        <p>abc</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td rowspan="4">This is the rowspan 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is a table with ten rows of three columns:

- The first column are all single-row cells;
- The second column is all single-row cells, except for one cell in the middle which spans four cells; and
- The third column is a single cell which spans all ten rows.

When the content of the cell in the third column exceeds the 'natural' vertical height of the other two columns the table expands the other columns to suit.  In Firefox each individual row is apportioned the same amount of space, so each row is the same height, as per the screenshot below:

[Screenshot of Firefox; vertical space is apportioned equally to all table rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEY71.jpg)

But in Chrome all of the vertical space seems to be given to the first row of the multi-row cell in the second column, leaving a gross imbalance in height between that row and all the others:

[Screenshot of Chrome; vertical space is allocated entirely to a single row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKV2k.jpg)

Searching Stackoverflow I found one relevant question:

[Table cells bad rendering with Google Chrome/Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706777/table-cells-bad-rendering-with-google-chrome-webkit)

... which says this is a webkit bug.  The 'solution' - to essentially avoid 'rowspan' entirely - won't work for me.  That question was raised more than ten years ago; I'm hoping there might be a solution now.

Is there any way to cause Chrome to distribute the excess height equally to all rows?  Thanks!